# How best to plug in dual monitors in dual GPUs?

Tags: mac, performance, development, gpu

How would you plug in two high-res monitors into a Mac with dual radeon pro 5700X GPUs to maximize system performance, specifically for rendering/programming:

1. Both monitors into the same GPU, and one GPU free for rendering
2. One monitor in each GPU
3. Doesn't matter in terms of performance